# Problem in loop

Tags: soql, error

I have this request:
**for loop that retrieve 10 object from Acccount and their childs and for each account display the Account and its related childrens**

Here is my sample code:

```
for (Account acc : [SELECT Name, (SELECT LastName,id,Email from Contact) from Account limit : 10]){
system.debug(acc);
}
```

Am having the following errors:

> Didn't understand relationship 'Contact' in FROM part of query call.
>   If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append
>   the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your
>   WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Any help please

Answer (score 7):

The problem is in `"FROM Contact"`

You can't subselect on an object,but on a relationship to an other object. So you have to use the name of the relationship, which is `Contacts` in this case

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT LastName,id,Email from Contacts) from Account limit  10
```

Note that limit also doesn't require an `:` or `=` if you have the value in the query directly. The `:` is when you are binding to a variable.